# Draggable Borderless Window and Button click handler in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, window, mouseevent

The Button handler doesnt work because of the DragMove call in Window mouse down handler. Is there any way how to let the events bubbling? I tried set up `e.Handled` to false, but it does not work.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                    
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {    
        this.DragMove();
        e.Handled = false;
    }   

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("zde");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `The Button handler doesnt work because of the DragMove call`

Actually, it doesn't work, because the first fires is an event at the `Button.Click`, and when it works, it conflicts with the events like: MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseUp, MouseDown and for routed events `e.Handled` property is *false* by default.

To make this work, you need to define an `PreviewMouseDown` event, but it's a Tunnel event, this means that it will go down of the `VisualTree` hierarchy, therefore it is triggered before the Bubble events.

Example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        ...
        PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown" ... />
```

`Code-behind`

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        this.DragMove();
}
```